# 20.04 upgrade aborted when comparing modified files - how to jump back in where the installer stopped

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, updates

I updated from 19.10 to 20.04. At one point, I had to compare two files to decide which to keep. I looked through the differences and was sure which one to keep. I'm used to using nano and hit `CTRL+x` to exit - but it was not nano and it stopped the upgrade script instead.
I gave it a `dpkg --configure -a` and a `sudo apt update && apt upgrade && apt dist-upgrade` and my system seems to be working. However, I think issues might lure in the dark...
Is there a way to start the upgrade routine again?

Would
    `sudo apt-get install –reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
    `sudo apt-get build-dep ubuntu-desktop`
do the trick?
Or should I rather boot from USB and try the reinstall from there? ([Reinstall Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation))

Thank you for your thoughts on this!

Comment: You can try `do-release-upgrade`, but I suspect it wouldn't do anything. I am not sure you need tricks, in fact, there seems to be some merit to do nothing.

Comment: I tried this right away, without success. But thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Or maybe someone just knows what the steps in the install routine of a release upgrage are, so I could perform them manually.